# If dG is a state function, why do reversible and irreversible paths differ?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

For a reversible process at constant T,P in a closed system with no non-expansion work dG = 0. For an irreversible process under the same conditions, dG < 0. Since dG is a state function I would expect two process at the same T,P to give the same result just as dS is calculated for reversible processes but can be applied to any process with the same initial and final states. I suspect that I have incorrectly assumed that the states for dG are the same but I'm unsure.

Comment: G is not only a function of T and P, but also a function of chemical composition.

Comment: Right, but in this case I'm assuming single phase pure substances so that n is constant.

Comment: For the same initial and final states of the system, it has to be the same.  If you have a single phase pure substance and the initial and final temperatures and pressure are the same, then $\Delta G$ of the system is zero, irrespective of the path.  Of course, the intermediate states can vary, and the changes in the surroundings may be different.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example that we can discuss?

Comment: I think I figured it out. For a constant T,P process heat is dq=dH and is no longer a path function so that dG=0 regardless of whether the process is reversible or irreversible. dG is only <0 if there is a change in another variable such as n1,n2... or if we get rid of the constant P condition.

Comment: I have a little different perspective for you to consider.  Either no process has taken place at all, or the system has experienced a cyclic process, such that its final state is the same as its initial state.  If the cyclic process was irreversible, then any entropy that was generated within the system during the process (as a result of the irreversibility) has been transferred to the surroundings.

Comment: dG = -TdS_total right? So if entropy was transferred to the surroundings, wouldn't dG<0?

Comment: Also my question is similar to https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42758/why-at-constant-pressure-and-temperature-gibbs-energy-change-of-a-process-can-be?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa except that I'm interested in the contradiction when dG<0 for no reaction.

Comment: The total $\Delta G$ would be negative, but the $\Delta G$ of the system would be zero.