# Gibbs Free Energy and dependence on temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics

So, I have read that change in Gibbs free energy is defined under constant pressure and temperature, i.e
$$\Delta G= \Delta H -T \Delta S $$

but for an ideal gas change in entropy of system can be written as
$$\Delta S= nC_pln(T_2/T_1) + nRln(p_1/p_2)$$
this formula implies that change in entropy at constant temperature and pressure is 0.
Also for an ideal gas change in enthalpy is only a function of temperature so for an ideal gas at constant temperature and pressure change in enthalpy would be 0.
But as I said above $\Delta G$ is defined at constant temperature and pressure, so wouldn't change in gibbs free enregy for an ideal gas always be 0?

PS I have read some related answers but they have not helped me solve this query.
Some Read answers -
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716364/how-can-the-gibbs-free-energy-equation-be-at-constant-temperature-and-pressure

[Why at constant pressure and temperature Gibbs energy change of a process can be negative?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42758/why-at-constant-pressure-and-temperature-gibbs-energy-change-of-a-process-can-be)

Comment: *change in Gibbs free energy is defined under constant pressure*   G is defined regardless of conditions as G = H - TS, but only at T=const (p=const is not required) it can be written as ΔG=ΔH-Δ(TS)=ΔH-TΔS.

Comment: But finally for us to write $\Delta G= \Delta H -T \Delta S$ doesn't your statement imply that the conditions should be constant pressure and temperature

Comment: No, it does not. G as well as H are especially useful and usually used at isobaric conditions (like A and U at isochoric ones), but the above formula does not have isobaric requirement, being directly derived from G definitions and isothermic requirement.

Comment: Ok, so the equation is valid for isothermal conditions, I guess many places it is written wrong then, couple books I have, have written it as both constant temperature and pressure.

Comment: Well, it is valid for that too. If something is said to be valid for 2 simultaneous conditions, it does not generally imply it cannot be valid for just one of the conditions.

Comment: But wouldn't under those conditions $\Delta G$ be always 0?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148620/discussion-between-poutnik-and-bm27).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is happening no change in a (not reacting) ideal gas system at isothermic and isobaric conditions.

Therefore, unless no chemical reaction is happening, $ΔG =  0$

Similarly, for reversible processes at isothermic and isobaric conditions:
\begin{align}
ΔS&=Q/T\\
ΔH&=Q_p\\
ΔG&=ΔH-TΔS=Q_p-Q_p=0
\end{align}

If there is ongoing spontaneous process, like chemical reaction, $ΔG \lt 0$. We then say the process is exergonic. Note that a process need not to be exothermic ($ΔH \lt 0$) to be exergonic, if balanced by the system entropy increase. See e.g. dissolving of $\ce{KNO3}$ or $\ce{KClO3}$, which is endothermic but spontaneous.